# An effective way to test arbitrary precision methods

Tags: unit-testing

This is sort of like the chicken and egg problem. In order to ensure that my arbitrary precision code works correctly, I need to rely on other, existing bignum implementations.

This is relatively easy in Java. We already have the `java.math` package to help in this situation. So far, I've used it to test my basic arithmetic methods.
Now the problem is obvious. I can't port my approach to other languages without procuring a bignum library first. So my question is

> **How can I easily and quickly write tests for code implementing arbitrary precision algorithms?**

---

I can't seem to be able to add more than one tag from my phone for some reason.

Comment: Do you already have a `toString` and `parse` implementation? If you can save to and load from files (preferably in text format) then the data can be loaded into another implementation in a different language.

Comment: You can also evaluate different equivalent expressions and compare the results. E.g. in pseudo code `z := x * y`, `equal(z / x, y)`. Of course you can have several bugs that cancel each other out, but these kinds of tests should still catch some bugs.

Answer (score 4):

How would you test your arbitrary-precision package if there is no competing package available?

If you can't compare the outcome of your package with a competing package in the same language, you need to calculate the expected outcomes of the methods you are testing while you are writing the tests.

By calculating the expected results beforehand, you are not restricted by the availability of a bignum package in any language, because if push comes to shove, you can always perform the calculations by hand with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways how very high precision is needed to find a result that is very simple.

For example, use the straight forward Taylor formula to calculate exp (-100). The result is tiny, but adds up many *huge* terms. You will get a clearly wrong result if any of the multiplications or additions involved doesn't give the result it should.